# Sending email in Java?

Tags: java, email

Can anyone suggest a library for sending emails in Java?

Answer (score 13):

Try [Commons Mail](http://commons.apache.org/email/). This builds on the [Java Mail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) but makes it much more simple to use.

Comment: hey will common mail with work with gmail smtp server?

Comment: It works with any smtp server, just like any mail client.

Answer (score 8):

You may also want to take a look at the [Apache Commons Email library](http://commons.apache.org/email/).  It is featureful and easy to use.

You could do something along the lines of:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
...
String[] recipients = {"a@foo.com", "b@foo.com"};

SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");

for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
{
    email.addTo(recipients[i]);
}

email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
email.setSubject("Test message");
email.setMsg("This is a simple test of commons-email");
email.send();
```

The sample code is taken from the Commons Email example page, modified to show adding multiple recipients.  Hope that helps.

Comment: hey will this with work with gmail smtp server?

Comment: you need to authenticate properly, but when that is done, you can use it with gmail

Answer (score 5):

Spring has a mail wrapper layer as well:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mail.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use JavaMail API and you can get some basic knowledge about this from following tutorial [Fundamentals of the JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html)