# How to send email from a java web app

Tags: java, email

I have a java web application sitting on Tomcat/Apache.

I have a form which has to send email. What is the best way to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short and dirty copy-and-paste for sending a simple plain text  mail message using javamail [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html)

Tiny example of sending a plain text msg, using custom smtp host:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "your.mailhost.com");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@from.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("mail@to.com")});
    msg.setSubject("Subject Line");
    msg.setText("Text Body");
    Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: Can I add a file (like PDF) to this mail?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose these threads did appear when you posted your question:

[Sending mail from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287440/sending-mail-from-java)

[How do I send an e-mail in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884943/how-do-i-send-an-e-mail-in-java)

[How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail)

Answer (score 5):

You should look at [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-1-4-140512.html)

Additionally, you may want to look at [Fancymail](https://www.clazzes.org/projects/fancymail/), a small library to simplify usage of JavaMail API.

Comment: I remain mystified that `javax.mail` hasn't yet made it into JavaSE, but things like JAX-WS and SOAP have. It's damned peculiar.