# Java EE Sending Emails - What Library

Tags: java, email

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sending mail from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287440/sending-mail-from-java)
>   [Sending email in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848645/sending-email-in-java)

Hi folks,

I want to send emails out of my web application via my email server. I also want to use email templates.

Can you recommend a library? Is Apache-Commons appropriate? or even Java Mail API?

Answer (score 2):

- [java mail api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-139225.html)
- [Jakarta Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/)

[Sending mail from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287440/sending-mail-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

[how to send an email from jsp/servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757442/how-to-send-an-email-from-jsp-servlet)